# Tkinter Not Opening Issue with SQL

Tags: python, sql, database, tkinter

In this program the tkinter window only opens in the end when exit is given. I have tried various google searches but still couldn't find any solution. I hope it can be fixed...

Code:

```
import os
import platform
import pymysql
import tkinter
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
constr=pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="1234",database="Alureg")
print(constr)
mycursor=constr.cursor()
root=Tk()
root.geometry("900x600")
root.title("Alumni Registration System")
Tops=Frame(root)
Tops.pack(side=TOP)
f1=Frame(root)
f1.pack(side=LEFT)
f2=Frame(root)
f2.pack(side=BOTTOM)

a=""
b=""
c=""
d=""
e=""
f=""
g=""
h=""
i=""
j=""
k=""
l=""
m=""
n=""

def values():
   
    a=a.get()
    b=b.get()
    c=c.get()
    d=d.get()
    e=e.get()
    f=f.get()
    g=g.get()
    h=h.get()
    i=i.get()
    j=j.get()
    k=k.get()
    l=l.get()
    m=m.get()
    n=n.get()

Heading=Label(Tops,font=('helvetica',26,'bold'),text="Alumini Registration System",fg="Black",bg="cyan",bd=10)
Heading.grid(row=0,column=0)
fname= Label(f1, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),text="First Name",bd=16)
fname.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
lname= Label(f1, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),text="Last Name",bd=16)
lname.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
dob= Label(f1, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),text="Date Of Birth",bd=16)
dob.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
gender= Label(f1, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),text="Gender",bd=16)
gender.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
add_c= Label(f1, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),text="Corresponding Address",bd=16)
add_c.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
add_of= Label(f1, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),text="Official Address",bd=16)
add_of.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W)
email= Label(f1, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),text="Email ID",bd=16)
email.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W)
mob= Label(f1, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),text="Mobile Number",bd=16)
mob.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=W)
cur_c= Label(f1, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),text="City",bd=16)
cur_c.grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=W)
com= Label(f1, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),text="Company Name",bd=16)
com.grid(row=9, column=0, sticky=W)
desg= Label(f1, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),text="Designation",bd=16)
desg.grid(row=10, column=0, sticky=W)
start_y= Label(f1, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),text="Session Start Year",bd=16)
start_y.grid(row=11, column=0, sticky=W)
start_e= Label(f1, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),text="Session End Year",bd=16)
start_e.grid(row=12, column=0, sticky=W)
brach= Label(f1, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),text="Branch in College",bd=16)
brach.grid(row=13, column=0, sticky=W)

#textboxes
fname_box=Entry(f1, font=('arial',12,'bold'),textvariable=a,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue")
fname_box.grid(row=0,column=1)
lname_box=Entry(f1, font=('arial',12,'bold'),textvariable=b,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",)
lname_box.grid(row=1,column=1)
dob_box=Entry(f1, font=('arial',12,'bold'),textvariable=c,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",)
dob_box.grid(row=2,column=1)
gender_box=Entry(f1, font=('arial',12,'bold'),textvariable=d,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",)
gender_box.grid(row=3,column=1)
add_c_box=Entry(f1, font=('arial',12,'bold'),textvariable=e,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",)
add_c_box.grid(row=4,column=1)
add_of_box=Entry(f1, font=('arial',12,'bold'),textvariable=f,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",)
add_of_box.grid(row=5,column=1)
email_box=Entry(f1, font=('arial',12,'bold'),textvariable=g,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",)
email_box.grid(row=6,column=1)
mob_box=Entry(f1, font=('arial',12,'bold'),textvariable=h,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",)
mob_box.grid(row=7,column=1)
cur_c_box=Entry(f1, font=('arial',12,'bold'),textvariable=i,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",)
cur_c_box.grid(row=8,column=1)
com_box=Entry(f1, font=('arial',12,'bold'),textvariable=j,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",)
com_box.grid(row=9,column=1)
desg_box=Entry(f1, font=('arial',12,'bold'),textvariable=k,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",)
desg_box.grid(row=10,column=1)
start_y_box=Entry(f1, font=('arial',12,'bold'),textvariable=l,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",)
start_y_box.grid(row=11,column=1)
start_e_box=Entry(f1, font=('arial',12,'bold'),textvariable=m,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",)
start_e_box.grid(row=12,column=1)
brach_box=Entry(f1, font=('arial',12,'bold'),textvariable=n,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",)
brach_box.grid(row=13,column=1)
def RegisterAlumni():
    values()
    L=[]
    L.extend([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n])
    alumni=(L)
    sql="insert into alureg values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
    mycursor.execute(sql,alumni)
    constr.commit()
    print("You Have Been Succesfully Registered, Use your mobile number For Further Correspondence")

btnSubmit=Button(f2,bd=16,fg="black",font=('arial',16,'bold'),width=10,text="Submit",bg="silver",command=RegisterAlumni).grid(row=1,column=1)
    
def ViewAlumniDetails():
    print("Select the search criteria to View Details : ")
    print("1. Fname")
    print("2. Lname")
    print("3. Company")
    print("4. Stream")
    print("5. City")
    print("6. Session Start")
    print("7. To View All Records")
    ch=int(input("Enter the choice : "))
    if ch==1 :
        s=input("Enter First Name to Be Searched For")
        rl=(s,)
        sql="select * from alureg where fname like %s"
        mycursor.execute(sql,rl)
    elif ch==2:
        s=input("Enter Last Name to Be Searched For")
        rl=(s,)
        sql="select * from alureg where lname like %s"
        mycursor.execute(sql,rl)
    elif ch==3:
        s=input("Enter Company Name to Be Searched For")
        rl=(s,)
        sql="select * from alureg where cur_c=%s"
        mycursor.execute(sql,rl)
    elif ch==4:
        s=input("Enter Stream : ")
        rl=(s,)
        sql="select * from alureg where brach=%s"
        mycursor.execute(sql,rl)
    elif ch==5:
        s=input("Enter City : ")
        rl=(s,)
        sql="select * from alureg where cur_c=%s"
        mycursor.execute(sql,rl)
    elif ch==6:
        s=input("Enter Session Start Year ")
        rl=(s,)
        sql="select * from alureg where start_y=%s"
        mycursor.execute(sql,rl)
    elif ch==7:
        sql="select * from alureg"
        mycursor.execute(sql)
    res=mycursor.fetchall()
    print("The Alumni Details are as Follows")
    print("fname,lname,dob,gender,add_c,add_of,email,mob,cur_c,com,desg,start_y,start_e,brach)")
    for x in res:
        print(x)
def EditAlumni():
    mob=input("Enter Mobile number to be edited : ")
    sql="select * from alureg where mob=%s"
    ed=(mob,)
    mycursor.execute(sql,ed)
    res=mycursor.fetchall()
    for x in res:
        print(x)
    print("")
    fld=input("Enter the field which you want to edit : ")
    val=input("Enter the value you want to set : ")
    sql="Update alureg set " + fld +"='" + val + "' where mob='" + mob + "'"
    sq=sql
    mycursor.execute(sql)
    print("Editing Done : ")
    print("After correction the record is : ")
    sql="select * from alureg where mob=%s"
    ed=(mob,)
    mycursor.execute(sql,ed)
    res=mycursor.fetchall()
    for x in res:
        print(x)
    constr.commit()
def SearchAlumni(): 
    mob=input("Enter the Mobile number for the alumni to be viewed : ")
    sql="select * from alureg where mob=%s"
    rl=(mob,)
    mycursor.execute(sql,rl)
    res=mycursor.fetchall()
    if res==None:
        print("Record not Found . . . ")
        return
    print("The details of the students are : " )
    print("(fname,lname,dob,gender,add_c,add_of,email,mob,curr_c,com,desg,start_y,start_e,brach)")
    for x in res:
        print(x)
def DeleteAlumni():
    mob=input("Enter the Mobile number for the alumni to be deleted : ")
    sql="Delete from alureg where mob=%s"
    rl=(mob,)
    mycursor.execute(sql,rl)
    constr.commit()
def MainMenu():
    print("Enter 1 : To Register Alumni")
    print("Enter 2 : To View Alumni Details ")
    print("Enter 3 : To Edit Alumni Details ")
    print("Enter 4 : To Search Alumni ")
    print("Enter 5 : To delete Alumni")
    
    try:
        userInput = int(input("Please Select An Above Option: "))
    except ValueError:
        exit("You Had Enetered Wrong Choice")
    else:
        print("\n")
    if(userInput == 1):
        RegisterAlumni()
    elif (userInput==2):
        ViewAlumniDetails()
    elif (userInput==3):
        EditAlumni()
    elif (userInput==4):
        SearchAlumni()
    elif (userInput==5):
        DeleteAlumni()
    else:
        print("Enter correct choice. . . ")
        
MainMenu()
def AskChoiceAgain():
    AksChcRun = input("\n want To Run Again Y /n: ")
    while(AksChcRun.lower() == 'y'):
        MainMenu()
        AksChcRun = input("\nwant To Run Again Y/n: ")
        
AskChoiceAgain()
```

Attached is the screenshot of the sql database...
[SQL Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOqJ8.png)

Comment: Can you show a more reproducible program? A shorter one ie

Comment: @Arya I didn't get you reproducible program meaning?

Comment: Meaning...we can copy and paste the code and the error will be produced for us too. And do you actually want us to go through this entire code and find the error and then find a solution to it? Its better to just mark the error and the line that produce such error.

Comment: It might be because even if the app closes, the code is waiting for `input()` to be entered

Comment: And my suggestion would be (a trivial one but this makes it more understandable), write the functions first, and then write the code that needs to be executed first. This will make it understandable for us. Here, I can see only functions and the calling of the function below. What is exactly going to be executed first?

Comment: And in the function AskChoiceAgain(), the first should be 'Y', and not input.... because the value 'y' needs to be stored, and not the input statement. So first line will be:
AksChcRun = 'Y'
Try this out

Comment: Every other function works its just that the register part doesnt work...the tkinter window doesnt open first so that i can fill in the text box for the data to be entered in the database...

Comment: Copy and running the code, the tkinter window open first for me

Comment: Were you able to enter the data and store in database? cause when it opens and i enter it doesn't get stored...only blank spaces are stored...